# Combining query wit

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to "rearrange" a table like this one, but haven't figured out how to do it :p

```
Product    | Component | Quantity | Line
-----------------------------------------
EM08/100   | EM08      | 100      | 1
EMTE08/100 | EM08      | 100      | 1
EMTE08/100 | TE08S     | 100      |2
```

What this means is that the product EMTE08/100 is composed by 100 units of the EM08 combined with 100 units of TE08S.

The result i'm after is something like:

```
Product | Comp1 | Qty1 | Comp2 | Qty2
--------------------------------------
EM08    | EM08  | 100  | TE08S | 100
```

Experts, please? :)

TIA!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two lines, use conditional aggregation or `join`:

```
select t1.product, t1.component as comp1, t1.quantity as quant1,
       t2.component as comp2, t2.quantity as quant2
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.product = t2.product and t2.line = 2
where t1.line = 1;
```

I'm not quite sure why you've shorted the product name in your desired results table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon!!
Oops. I really did shortened the product name. But still couldn't get the query to work:
Im kinda new to this, and im not understanding the "from" part from your answer. From "t t1"?

Comment: @AlexVieira . . . `t` is your table name.